# React Formik enableReinitialize forces props.touched values to reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, formik

I have a data that is fetched from backend:

```
fetchUserData = async () => {
        ...fetching data

        this.setState({
          username: resp.data.data.uname
        });
  }
```

and I want Formik to validate the saved data from backend so I added enableReinitialize to Formik component:

```
<Formik
   initialValues={{
       username: this.state.username,
       password: this.state.password,
       confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword
   }}
   validationSchema={this.schema}
   enableReinitialize
>
```

but the problem is this, it now resets the props touched value:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: After the user changes the password field (or any other field for that matter), `touched` is being `reset`  and will have true only for password, causing the validation error that was previously displayed for the Username field to be hidden.

Comment: I have this issue also. all fields will become untouched when one of the state changed

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep the touched states after reinitialize.
We will have to implement a workaround to backup the `touched` object and use [`initialTouched`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#initialtouched-formiktouchedvalues) to restore it.

Or, give up `enableReinitialize` flag, if you do not want to reset the form every time a state value changed.
You can use Formik `innerRef` to manually call [`resetForm()`](https://formik.org/docs/migrating-v2#resetform), [`setValues()`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setvalues-fields-reactsetstateaction-field-string-any--shouldvalidate-boolean--promisevoid--formikerrorsvalues), [`setFieldValue()`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--promisevoid--formikerrors), etc, at the right time according to your use case.

Usage:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik"; // formik v2

const formRef = useRef();

<Formik
  innerRef={formRef} // <--- add this
  // enableReinitialize <--- remove this
  initialValues={{
       username: this.state.username, // now, state changes will not auto reflect in your form
       password: this.state.password,
       confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword,
  }}
  validationSchema={this.schema}
>
```

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

// reset form only when you really need to re-initialize the form
useEffect(() => {
    const { username, password, confirmPassword } = defaultStates;
    formRef.current.resetForm({
       values: {
          username: username,
          password: password,
          confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
       }
    });
}, [someTrigger]);


// listen to your state changes and update all fields
useEffect(() => {
    formRef.current.setValues(this.state);
}, [this.state]);


// listen to your state changes and update the field accordingly
useEffect(() => {
    formRef.current.setFieldValue("username", this.state.username);

    // or, even modify the touched flag
    formRef.current.setFieldTouched("username", false);
}, [this.state.username]);
```